# How can I turn off flash fill automatically in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, deployment

Flash fill breaks a lot of things in older excel documents. It causes maddeningly slow transfers from cell to cell after updating.

I am trying to find a way to turn off "flash fill" in Excel 2013 automatically before rolling the product out to the rest of the staff in my company.

Is there (preferably) a registry key that I can apply or a switch that I can include during the install that will turn this option off?

Here is an image of the setting that I am looking to turn off:

[image]

I haven't been able to find any documentation online about turning this off, other than this one page from MS:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/excel-help/turn-flash-fill-on-HA104043292.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your company is using Active directory then you can control this (and most other) Office settings via Group Policy.

Just grab the [Office 2013 Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35554) and install them.

Once they're installed, open the Group Policy Management console, create a new policy and edit it.

Navigate to `User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative templates -> Microsoft Excel 2013 -> Excel Options -> Advanced`

In there will be a policy named "Automatically Flash Fill".

From its help entry:

> This policy setting controls the "Automatically Flash Fill" option
>   found under File tab | Options | Advanced | Editing Options.
>
> If you enable or do not configure this policy setting, Excel will
>   enable automatic Flash Fill. This is the default behavior.
>
> If you disable this policy setting, Excel will turn off the Automatic
>   Flash Fill feature.

Note: Only 'Business' versions of Office 2013 support settings via group policy -- Excluding "Home and Business" which is more Home than Business, so it doesn't support the use of GPOs (it just ignores them).